# What is a fast way to apply different consecutive filters to data table

Tags: r, datatable

In order to apply a bootstrapping approach as described in the question of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481803/is-estimating-confidence-intervals-ci-with-different-sample-sizes-in-each-boot I need to apply different filters to a datatable and then create a new datatable which consists of the results of each filter step.

This is a reproducible example for the bootstrapping approach.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(compound= c(rep("ala", 5), rep("beta", 3), rep("phe", 8)),
             obs = c(rep(FALSE, 7), rep(TRUE, 9)))

boot::boot.ci(boot::boot(data.frame(var = dt$compound),
                         function(data, indices, stat_tab = dt){

                           comp_samp <- data[indices,]

                           fin_tab <- 
                           lapply(as.list(comp_samp), function(x, stat_tab_l = stat_tab){
                             stat_tab_l[x == compound]
                             })

                           fin_tab <- rbindlist(fin_tab)
                           
                           round(nrow(fin_tab[obs == TRUE])/nrow(fin_tab )*100,1)
                         },
                         R = 1000),
              index=1,
              type='basic')$basic
```

It generally works but is terribly slow which is a problem because my real datasets consist of hundreds of compounds and 10000s of observations.
Is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: I don't understand your proposed approach and I don't think it is valid bootstrap. It would help, if you showed how you would calculate the estimate from your original data. Maybe you actually want something like `boot::boot(dt, function(data, indices) data[indices, mean(obs) * 100, by = compound][, mean(V1)],R = 1000)`?

Comment: I would like to get a measure of the uncertainty of the percentage of true observations considering that drawn compounds where chosen at random from an unknown population size of compounds and there can be an enrichment of TRUE observation in some compounds. I would gladly include the whole data set but it is really big..

Comment: I am not a statistician but what I understood from the discussion in the provided SE link it should be valid to do so